# How this particular test case it is returning a empty string

Tags: java

I have written some code for adding two binary numbers. It's running fine for all other test cases but for this particular test case it is returning an empty string.

`num()` converts binary String to integer. and `bin()` converts number to binary string.

```
public class Solution {
    public String addBinary(String A, String B) {
        long result1=num(A)+num(B);
        return bin(result1);
    }
    public long num(String A){
        long result=0;
        for(int i =0;i<A.length();i++){
            long num1=Character.getNumericValue(A.charAt(i));
            result+=num1*(long)Math.pow(2,A.length()-1-i);
        }
        return result;
    }
    public String bin(long A){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while(A>0){
            sb.append(A%2);
            A/=2;
        }
        String s=sb.reverse().toString();
        return s;
    }
}

A : "10001100010111000101100010100110001001101010000010011010"
B : "101111000100100100111110010010101110101001100100101001111010011000000110"
Your function returned the following :

The expected returned value :
101111000100100111001010101001110100001100001010110011100100011010100000
```

Comment: What does `num(a)` and `num(b)` return when you debug the code?

Comment: Seems to be a long overflow, thus the number is negative and your loop never executes. Maximum long value is about 2^64, but that longer number has 72 binary digits.

Comment: As @tobias_k pointed out, while converting B to long it overflows, resulting in `result1` being overall negative `-3906125820404545893`.

Comment: So how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That second binary number is much too big for `long`, as it has 72 binary digits, whereas `long` only supports numbers up to 2<sup>64</sup>-1. Thus, you are getting a `long` overflow, your number is "negative", and the `while (A>0)` loop never executes.

Instead of `long`, you could just use `BigInteger`. You can either implement your algorithms analogeously for `BigInteger`, or just use its own binary conversion methods.

```
public String addBinary(String A, String B) {
    return bin(num(A).add(num(B)));
}

public BigInteger num(String A) {
    return new BigInteger(A, 2);
}

public String bin(BigInteger A) {
    return A.toString(2);
}
```

Of course, the much more interesting way would be to implement an *actual* binary adder yourself, adding and carrying individual digits (left as an excercise to the interested reader).

Comment: Thanks tobias_k! Got it.